Neovim command/codes to select visually the pasted text
How is neovim  command/setting to select visually selection of the pasted data that has just been pasted as gv can't do so?

You can use the  `[ and  `] marks to go to the first and last characters of the last changed text. After pasting text, this will be the pasted section. See :help `[ for more details.
To select from below the inserted text up to its first character, do
v`]

if you're anywhere and want to select first and last inserted characters, do
v`]o`[

The o goes to the other end of the Visual selection as documented in :help v_o.
For your convenience, you can create a mapping using the following Vimscript
:nnoremap <Leader>gv v`]o`[

or Lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '<Leader>gv', 'v`]o`[')

